# Lubridate timezone handling

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following string desribing a date and time in Central European
Summer Time: "2021-09-23 12:00:00".
In fact, I've got a whole, long column of such time points.
For certain reasons I have to handle these times with functions in the 'lubridate'
package. Using 'as_datetime' I get

```
t0 = "2021-09-23 12:00:00"
t1 = as_datetime(t0); t1
## [1] "2021-09-23 12:00:00 UTC"
```

that is, `as_datetime` uses the hours and minutes given and adds Universal
Time "UTC" as time zone. Supplying the time zone CEST gives instead

```
t1 = as_datetime(t0, tz = "CEST"); t1
## [1] "2021-09-23 10:00:00 CEST"
```

that is, changes the time, what I don't want.

What I would like to get (what I really need) is "2021-09-23 12:00:00 CEST",
that is changing the time zone without changing the time.

I tried `force_tz` and `with_tz`, but that didn't work either.

What I am also wondering is why 'lubridate' converts 12:00:00 UST to
10:00:00 CEST, because CEST is the same as GMT+2 and UTC is GMT+0, so
the result should actually be the other way around.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I try the code in the question on R 4.2.1 Windows and lubridate 1.8.0 I get a warning message *In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'CEST'*

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- On Linux, R 4.2.1 and lubridate 1.8.0, when I say `as_datetime(t0, tz="")` it automatically returns "2021-09-23 12:00:00 CEST", so the system appears to know what CEST is, and that this is my time zone right now. I have no idea why this is different on MS Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
t0 = "2021-09-23 12:00:00"


library(lubridate)
#1 

t1 = as_datetime(t0, tz = "Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2021-09-23 12:00:00 CEST"

or

#2
t1 = as_datetime(t0, tz = "CST6CDT")

[1] "2021-09-23 12:00:00 CDT"
```

Comment: Your tip was helpful. Using `with_tz(t1, "Europe/Berlin")` does convert the time to the correct time in the new time zone -- while using "CEST" does *not* change the time, only the time zone. Though 'lubridate' does recognize CEST as a time zone (on Linux at least), it does not handle it correctly when converting times between different time zones!